# How to add checkbox enabled textboxes only?

Tags: vb.net

I am using a checkbox(s) to enable textbox(s) where a user can enter an amount of an item wanted. Each item has a different price. I am trying to add the enabled textboxs for a grand total. I cant figure out how to avoid errors when a textbox is not enabled. How do I call only enabled textboxs? here is what I have.

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    TextBox4.Text = TxtBox.Text + TxtPav.Text + TxtLawn.Text
    TextBox5.Text = 
End Sub
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        TxtBox.Enabled = True
    Else
        TxtBox.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox2.CheckedChanged
    If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
        TxtPav.Enabled = True
    Else
        TxtPav.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub CheckBox3_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox3.CheckedChanged
    If CheckBox3.Checked = True Then
        TxtLawn.Enabled = True
    Else
        TxtLawn.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Textbox5 is where I am adding the total. Textbox4 adds the number of items being sold.
I have tried-

```
 Textbox5.text = txtbox * 75 + txtpav.text * 30 + txtLawn * 21
```

I get errors when a textbox is not enabled.

Comment: See [Decimal.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx).  txtbox and txtLawn aren't referencing there Text property.  Don't forget those properties are *strings*, not number values.  Best to convert them first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a variable and use cumulative addition. Then check for each checkbox. You are getting the error because you are trying to perform an operation on a control that has no value and is not enabled.

```
 Dim total as double = 0
 If checkbox1.checked then
  total += (Cdbl(txtbox.text) * 75)
 end if
 if checkbox2.checked then
  total += (Cdbl(txtpav.text) * 30)
 end if
 if checkbox3.checked then
  total += (Cdbl(txtLawn.text) * 21)
 end if
  Textbox5.text = total.ToString
```

Comment: I do..I guess that's what i get when i rely on VS' tooltips while programming.. sloppy syntax recall